# Movie where people disappear when they're out of sight

Tags: story-identification

I saw this sometime in the last five years and it felt like it was probably from around 2015. The era of mobile phones, at least.

It begins with some friends meeting up for a weekend away in a cabin overlooking a mountainside.

In the morning, one of them is missing, and they set out in search of them. They find an empty house or two and while they're out of sight of the main characters' viewpoint, people gradually disappear.

There's a scene where the few remaining are escaping wild dogs by cycling downhill, but one crashes and gets left behind. When the rest go back... they're gone.

The final scene is in the cabin of a boat.

Comment: Not the movie you're asking about, but a similar plot device is used in the Star Trek TNG episode ["Remember Me"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remember_Me_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)): the ship's doctor notices that people are disappearing when out of her sight, and only she remembers them.

Comment: Not the movie you're asking about, but in [Mystery Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_Men) one of the characters, Invisible Boy, is "a superhero who can only become invisible if nobody is looking".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think this might be [The End (2012)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_(2012_film))

In addition to people inexplicably disappearing when out of sight, there are a couple key things that line up with your description.

The bikes and  the dogs:

> Hours later, the remaining four – Felix, Eva, Sara and Maribel –
> arrive at a caravan park, but it too is completely deserted. They find
> bicycles, collect some food, and decide to ride to the nearest town,
> but just as they are about leave they are suddenly surrounded by a
> pack of ravenous German Shepherd dogs, which begin to attack them.
> They are forced to abandon the food and flee for their lives on the
> bicycles, with the dogs in hot pursuit, but just as the pack is about
> to catch Sara, the dogs inexplicably turn and run the other way as if
> in fear of something ahead of the group. Moments later, Felix, who is
> riding in front, hears the panicked Sara sobbing and calling to him
> not to leave her; he tries to reassure her, but moments later he
> realises he can no longer hear her, and when he, Maribel and Eva stop,
> Sara has vanished, and only the bicycle she was riding remains on the
> side of the road.

And the ending with a boat:

> Now apparently the only survivors of the catastrophe, Felix and Eva
> sail out to sea. Felix reveals that, at the car crash site, he had
> also found the torn-out final page of Ãngel's prophetic sketchbook,
> which seems to indicate that only Eva will survive. They go to sleep
> that night on the yacht, expecting that Felix will vanish, but they
> awake the next morning both still alive and together. The final scene
> shows the boat sailing into an unknown future as it fades out of sight
> into a luminous mist.

The reason this was so hard to find is that it's actually a Spanish film. After multiple failed searches that only led me to "Don't Blink" (the other answer), and failed attempts to search for films listed as similar to "Don't Blink", I decided to scan through the "Don't Blink" reviews on IMDB to see if anyone compared it to other films. That's where someone mentioned "The End".

Comment: That's it! Thank-you. I either don't remember it being Spanish or saw it dubbed I guess.

Answer (score 20):

Could this be [Don’t Blink](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1572306/?ref_=ext_shr_lnk) by Travis Oates?

> Don't Blink is a 2014 American psychological horror film written and directed by Travis Oates. It stars an ensemble cast that includes Mena Suvari, Brian Austin Green, Joanne Kelly, and Zack Ward, who also produced. A group of ten friends visit a remote resort, which they subsequently find empty. As they attempt to find out what happened to the other guests, they are horrified to find that they too are disappearing. It received a limited release on September 18, 2014

Though the ending does not take place on a boat cabin, it does show the final character, Claire panicking when she realizes she’s all alone in the end. It also features people just randomly disappearing when out of sight.

The film is indicated by IMDb as fully released in 2014, very close to the year you mentioned.

Comment: I've just watched the trailer and this isn't it, although it has some striking similarities in the earlier parts of the trailer. There's nothing in the film I'm thinking of about blinking (how very Doctor Who!) and nobody gets injured or talks about retribution or anything as dramatic as that, and there aren't any other people at all (the trailer for that one shows them seeing a group of officials including what looks like Robert Picardo)